# Nesting functions within the IF statement in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have three fields within a spreadsheet that I want to concatenate into one (the locality column). However, not all of the time all three columns have data within them. The goal is to have one continuous string with each column separated by a comma and the entire string end with a period.

**Example data:**

| locality | placename | localityname | localitydirections |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | Tulsa |  |
|  | City Park | Tulsa |  |
|  | Overlook | Chicago Ohio | Turn right at the traffic light |
|  |  |  | From the house turn left at the stop light |

**Desired Output:**

| locality | placename | localityname | localitydirections |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tulsa. |  | Tulsa |  |
| City Park, Tulsa. | City Park | Tulsa |  |
| Overlook, Chicago Ohio, Turn right at the traffic light. | Overlook | Chicago Ohio | Turn right at the traffic light. |
| From the house turn left at the stop light. |  |  | From the house turn left at the stop light |

## I have tried the following code, but I am met with an error. This code is assuming:

'locality' = Column A

'placename' = Column B

'localityname' = Column C

'localitydirections' = Column D

and the rows present are rows 1 - 5

First I used the formula

=B2&", "&C2&", "&D2&"." and dragged it down to auto populate the remaining fields.

**However it was giving me the following outcome:**

| locality | placename | localityname | localitydirections |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| , Tulsa, . |  | Tulsa |  |
| City Park, Tulsa, . | City Park | Tulsa |  |
| Overlook, Chicago Ohio, Turn right at the traffic light. | Overlook | Chicago Ohio | Turn right at the traffic light. |
| , , From the house turn left at the stop light. |  |  | From the house turn left at the stop light |

The punctuation becomes problematic with the blank fields.

What function could fix this? My initial thought was an IF function.

Comment: Use `TEXTJOIN` if you have it.

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2019 and above use `TEXTJOIN` formula with *ignore_empty* parameter set to `TRUE`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,B2:D2)&"."
```

Result:

[image]